# Reacts js TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to move to next pages as i change the url
Here is some of my code for web app in react js. I am trying for pagination but I am unable to access params. How can I access the params as these are also not showing on console as I tried using `console.log()`.

```
const Products = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const page = props.match.params.page ? props.match.params.page : 1;
  const getData = () => {
    productService
      .getProduct(page)
      .then((data) => {
        setProducts(data.products);
        setTotal(data.total);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  React.useEffect(getData, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products List:</h1>
      {userService.isAdmin() && (
        <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.addBtn}>
          <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
      )}
      <div className="container">
        {products.length == 0 ? (
          <p>No Product Found!</p>
        ) : (
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {products.map((product, index) => (
              <SingleProduct key={index} product={product} onDelete={getData} />
            ))}
          </Grid>
        )}
        <Grid items xs={12}>
          total: {total}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simple. Your object defined in `props.match` is not defined and therefore the error is throw. A simple solution for that is using optional chaining.

```
    const page = props.match?.params?.page || 1;
```

You can also use the [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm package for validating your components properties. Something like this would validate and define a default value for your component prop.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Products = (props) => {...};

Products.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      page: PropTypes.number,
    }).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

Products.defaultProps = {
  match: { params: {page: 1} },
};
```

Finally, whenever you use `useEffect` make sure you're observing the right parameters for executing the callback. In your case it makes sense to observe for changes in the `page` variable since you are updating your component state using this hook. **If you don't do this even if you change the value of your page property your component state will not update.**

```
React.useEffect(getData, [page]);
```

Comment: Got it, Thank You Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Just use optional chaining

```
const page = props.match?.params?.page || 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are checking the params for a number. By default the params value is a string. You can fix your issue by converting it as a number using parseInt.

```
....
   const getData = () => {
   productService
     .getProduct(parseInt(page))
     .then...
....
```

Hope it helped.